# How to Install Knife on the Linux machine,?

Tags: client, config, chef-infra

I have installed Chef server on One Physical Linux node successfully,
Now i am trying to install chef-client on the other Linux VM,
Unfortunately i am getting below error.

```
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/webui.pem
Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable
```

so copied the `webui.pem` from chef server to Linux Client
tried to execute knife client List

```
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000 as admin with key /etc/chef/webui.pem
Response:  Failed to authenticate. Ensure that your client key is valid.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

To use knife you need to be logged in as an admin user. Either copy down the servers admin.pem key or better still create a new admin user and use its key.

Another thing to fix is make sure the node_name used to login matches the key you're using. (The error message suggests you're using "admin"):

```
node_name                'myuser'
client_key               '/home/me/.chef/keys/myuser.pem'
```